# How to shade only selected areas for an inscribed circle in a square

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve what I have drawn in the sketch below:

[image: goal]

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick](0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[thick] (2,2) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. We can draw the square with a fill color first then draw a circle with a white fill color upon the square.
2. we can also use a single path with the `even odd color` option that fill the square and draw the circle without the white fill color.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray,thick](0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[fill=white,thick] (2,2) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[even odd rule,fill=gray,thick](0,0) rectangle (4,4) (2,2) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I am relatively new in TeX.SE In my previous answers I have so far always tried  to not bring substantial modifications to the preamble provided in the MWE by the OP. So thank's again I will remember your advice next times